# embedding a text editor into a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created a text edit program, and i want to add other features such as a button. I need to embed this into widget (so like the text editor is a panel ontop of the gui, and the button is also like a panel) sorry for java reference, dont know what they are called in pyqt4, but I don't know how to do this using PQT4 with Python 3.x. 
I want to achieve the following: 
![enter image description here][1]

Here is my code for the text editor

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Notepad(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Notepad, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):



        newAction = QtGui.QAction('New', self)
        newAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        newAction.setStatusTip('Create new file')
        newAction.triggered.connect(self.newFile)

        saveAction = QtGui.QAction('Save', self)
        saveAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveAction.setStatusTip('Save current file')
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

        openAction = QtGui.QAction('Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        closeAction = QtGui.QAction('Close', self)
        closeAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        closeAction.setStatusTip('Close Notepad')
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)

        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pygame Simplified text editor')
        self.show()

    def newFile(self):
        self.text.clear()

    def saveFile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        filedata = self.text.toPlainText()
        f.write(filedata)
        f.close()


    def openFile(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        self.text.setText(filedata)
        f.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    notepad = Notepad()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Question is too broad, please specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what "another GUI" is, I will just assume it's another PyQt4 program. In which case, all you have to do is make the QMainWindow behave like a normal widget.

Firstly, change `Notepad.__init__` so that it can have a parent:

```
class Notepad(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Notepad, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
```

and then adjust the [window flags](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) so that it doesn't behave like a top-level window:

```
class AnotherGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnotherGUI, self).__init__()
        self.notepad = Notepad(self)
        self.notepad.setWindowFlags(
            self.notepad.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit', self)
        ...
```

Comment: @Pro-grammer. Your question is still totally unclear. Please explain why my answer is not a solution.

Comment: I worked it out, I needed to make a class which inherits a widget :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though :-)